# Running a bash script within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script for the installation of an environment manager but it means that I have to install something within multiple directories. See my other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77621/bash-script-installing-within-multiple-directories) for more details. But this led me to rethink my approach.

I was now thinking of making it 3 separate bash scripts. Then the one will just call the other. Here is the thing: I need to some how `source .bash_profile` within the parent shell. The question is, would a bash script that has been called within a bash script be running in a new shell or the parent shell or would it be in a new shell within the host bash script shell within the parent shell?

'shell-ception' I know its cooking my brain. i would really like to automate this process and this is the wall I am facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute a command in a shell it is always executed as a child process to this shell unless

1. it is a shell builtin (like `cd`)
2. it is sourced (`. /path/to/file`, `source /path/to/file`)
3. it is executed via `exec`

You can easily check that with `ps -e -o pid,ppid,user,args`.

`source .bash_profile` influences subshells only if the variables have been marked for export (see `declare -x`).

Comment: In most shells `(cmd)` (where `cmd` is not builtin) doesn't fork an additional process. More generally in `(cmd1; ...; cmdn)`, `cmdn` is executed by the subshell process (exception to that (for most shells) is when a `trap` is set in the subshell).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Strange; I must have wrongly remembered that. I had a look at that situation a few days ago. But maybe something was different then and I misinterpreted the special case for the general one. Good that someone proofreads...

Answer (score 2):

This are the practical differences:

- Running a command makes the shell to create a child process. Any environment variable previously defined in the child is lost to the parent process.
- Using `source` the script is forced to run in the current process (within the parent process). Then, the environment variables in the script will remain.